# Full row selection in primeng p-tree

Tags: html, angular, tree, primeng

I'm trying to style the primeng p-tree in the way our designer wants it to be.
My first problem is that I need a full row selection where the hover style and the selected style start at left:0px and end add right:0px. I found the following post on github => 
[Request on github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3246) but I can't figure out how to use it. At the moment My note looks like this =>

[image]

My second problem is, that I have to get rid of the expand and collapse icon because the tree is always expanded.

Can any one help my?

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Michael

Comment: do you have to use primeng tree? maybe its better to use bootstrap, you could easily add same functionality and you can style the way you want it https://codepen.io/Sp00ky/pen/aZJWLa/. I had to implement something similar for the tree, can send you some code if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. If you overwrite the css class ui-treenode-content-selected you can adjust the whole DIV that is around the node and not only the node in the DIV

```
.ui-treenode-content-selected {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #416172;
}
```